# Get JSlider value in tests using AssertJ

Tags: java, swing, assertj

I use JUnit and AssertJ tests for my Swing app written in Java 8. I'd like to test whether slider value is changed when a button is clicked, but I didn't find any way to get a current value from a slider.

I've initialized the app at the beginning of the test

```
Vizar frame = GuiActionRunner.execute(() -> new Vizar());
window = new FrameFixture(frame);
window.show();
```

into `window` variable. I would like to have something like this

```
int a = window.slider("zoomSlider").getValue();
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AssertJ-Swing, all the fixtures that you can retrieve via `JFrameFixture` have a method `target()` that retrieves the target component.

For your problem, this means that you will have to write

```
int a = window.slider("zoomSlider").target().getValue();
```